# Unable to get TextBox text in DataList

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a textbox in a datalist I'm trying to access in edit mode:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dl1" OnEditCommand="dl1_EditCommand"
                         OnCancelCommand="dl1_CancelCommand" OnUpdateCommand="dl1_UpdateCommand"
                         runat="server">
...
    <asp:TextBox ID="tbType" Width="600" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>' />
```

CodeBehind:

```
protected void dl1_UpdateCommand(object sender, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("tbType");
}
```

My code executes, **but the value of the textbox is always empty, even though I have a value in it!** I don't get either my updated text or the default text - I get a null. It finds the textbox, I've even opened the inspector to view its text...

This hasn't happened before and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've never had a problem like this before...

Full disclosure - this is a datalist inside a usercontrol.

**UPDATE**

Showing `EditItemTemplate` tags as requested.

The value is "" - I get a reference to the textbox, but no value.

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <td><asp:LinkButton ID="lbEdit" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="update" CausesValidation="false" />
    <br /><asp:LinkButton ID="lbCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="cancel" CausesValidation="false" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Id") %>' />
        <asp:TextBox ID="tbType" Width="600" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Type") %>' />
    </td>
    <td></td>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Is the value empty or `tb==null`? Also show the `EditItemTemplate` tags since that is essential for the question.

Comment: @TimSchmelter added code as requested.

Comment: Is your viewstate disabled by any chance?

Comment: No, viewstate is active. It's in a usercontrol, and in an updatepanel. I take it out of the updatepanel (first thing I though of), and it still doesn't work...